# Why do I get this output from my while read loop?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, output

I wrote a script that used information from a CSV file to create a string from it. The script goes through each line, generates a string from it and appends it to the string of the previous line. So I end up with a long string that consists of information from all the lines. The result of the script should be to print only the final string.

My problem: As you can see in the output in the terminal, the script outputs every step (in this case 3) strings and not just the final one. Why is it like this?

**This is my CSV:**

```
42342;home;2020-01-12;2020-01-13
45235;work;2020-04-12;2020-04-13
68787;photo;2020-05-12;2020-05-13
```

**This is my bash script:**

```sh
getPhotosCommand(){
    com=""
    header="ID;DIR;START_DATE;END_DATE" 
    
    while read line; do
        IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< "$line"

        dir=${array[2]}
        start_date=${array[3]}
        end_date=${array[4]}

        newCom="cli-search -d $dir -s $start_date -e $end_date >> photos.txt && "
        com=$com$newCom
    
    echo "$com cli-search download -d $dir -p @photos.txt"

    done < $file_new_photos
}
```

**Output in terminal:**

```
cli-search -d home -s 2020-01-12 -e 2020-01-13 >> photos.txt && cli-search download -d home -p @photos.txt
cli-search -d home -s 2020-01-12 -e 2020-01-13 >> photos.txt && cli-search -d home -s 2020-04-12 -e 2020-04-13 >> photos.txt && cli-search download -d home -p @photos.txt
cli-search -d home -s 2020-01-12 -e 2020-01-13 >> photos.txt && cli-search -d home -s 2020-04-12 -e 2020-04-13 >> photos.txt && cli-search -d home -s 2020-05-12 -e 2020-05-13 >> photos.txt &&  cli-search download -d home -p @photos.txt
```

Comment: ‘_Why is it like this?_’ Because you put an `echo` in the loop…?

Comment: @Biffen The `echo` is after the loop. The loop is only the `while`, right? Or where the echo should be? The result of the function should be to have echoed just the final string.

Comment: No, the `echo` is inside the loop. The loop ends at `done`. The (incorrect) indentation doesn’t mean anything; Bash isn’t Python.

Comment: Your parsing code could be rather drastically simplified to `while IFS=";" read -r id dir start_date end_date; do`...

Comment: The loop body looks vaguely like you are trying to save a command in a variable. This is basically never a good idea; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line is appending to the "$com" variable due to this line:

```
com=$com$newCom
```

and your echo statement looks like it should be outside of the loop, ie. after the `done` line.

If you would like just the last line, then move the echo statement.
If you would like 3 lines, change your echo statement to use `$newCom` instead of `$com`.